# How can I keep a clone of a folder?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, uti

I have a folder with Docs in on a Time Capsule, I would also like this same folder to be in Documents on Mac.

I want both to update whenever a file is changed or added.

Do you know of an automate command or a piece of software that will do this without me having to initiate it manually.

Comment: Will you be adding to one or both folders. Because a clone is a copy. So implies you will have one original folder and one copy of that folder. Not two original folders kept in sync. This make a lot of difference when working out how to do either. The first is simpler..

Comment: @markhunte I am looking to add to both folders really, as I use a Mac and a MacBook with the same TC.

Comment: Then that maybe hard to do. You need a system that not only passes on the files, but also timestamps and file info details to each Mac. So each mac can check against those details and the file.

Comment: @markhunte exactly right, was hoping there was a product that would do this for me.

Comment: Just found this with a google. Not used it but it says it can "sync your home and work computers—even if they're not connected—by syncing them both with an external hard drive serving as a "shuttle" for your data."  http://decimus.net/Synk/SynkPro.html

Comment: I used Synk for a while and was very pleased with their service.

Comment: @Graeme-Hutchison, done. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Just found [SynkPro](http://decimus.net/Synk/SynkPro.html) with a google. Not used it but it says it can "sync your home and work computers—even if they're not connected—by syncing them both with an external hard drive serving as a "shuttle" for your data."

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for you. First is a paid app such as Folder Watch [(App Store link)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/folderwatch/id408224368?mt=12) that offers a simple GUI to select folders to keep in sync.

The second option would be to set up an [Automator workflow](http://www.bananica.com/Geek-Stuff/Synchronize-two-folders-on-a-Mac-with-Automator-and-Rsync/) that executes the following rsync command:

```
rsync -va --delete "$source/" "$target/"
```

(Where $source and $target are paths to the folders you wish to keep in sync.)

Comment: Thats, I may do the Automater tutorial, Folder watch will only sync one way, which isnt great for my needs as I access teh Time Capsule on another Mac (like a server)

Comment: Having tried automate it will only sync one way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac OS X 10.7.2+ (Lion) on a Mac, you can try using iCloud.

Set up both machines with the same iCloud account, and ensure that "Documents & Data" is checked in:

```
System Preferences > iCloud > [√] Documents & Data.
```

Navigate to "~/Library/Mobile Documents" and create an alias of this folder on your desktop on both machines.

Any item placed into that folder should appear on the other within a few seconds.

Bare in mind, this solution is officially unsupported, and as far as I know uses your WAN connection to sync rather than do so locally. Also, it is most likely subject to the space limitations of your iCloud account, so going with something like Dropbox or Synk may be a more suitable solution in the short term.

Comment: It's worth noting that besides being undocumented/unsupported, this is also rather limited in the amount of data that can be stored.

Answer (score 0):

To sync both ways, and without using Internet storage clients like Drop box, I recommend using [Chronosync](http://econtechnologies.com/).  It's not the cheapest, but it's massively flexible.  You set up a source and a destination, and provide configurable options for when and how to sync.  You can sync both ways, sync but archive any files that are deleted, sync one way, sync when a machine logs into the same LAN, sync on a timed schedule, perform trial syncs to check what will change, filter against files within the sync area etc etc.  I'm not affiliated with them in any way, but I use it to maintain 2 home directories on seperate Macs.

If you want to sync one way, you can use Folder Actions to make a copy for added files, but I don't think it will cater for file modification.

You say the folder is on your time machine drive, but you don't say how you connect to this drive (USB/Wireless etc) - you need to ensure that the drive that the folder is mountable on in available when performing a sync, whatever method you use.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look I didn't say Time Machine, I said Time Capsule, this is a WiFi hard drive, so connected over LAN.

Answer (score -2):

If you are willing to switch "Time Capsule" for "some service in the cloud" this is exactly what [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) does really really well :)

Comment: I've got dropbox. This isn't big enough